# JPA: manually increment, avoid race condition (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, jpa, race-condition

I think I have a rather simple task of manually incrementing ID when adding a new record to the table, based on some conditions.

Let's say I have tables Book and Chapter. Chapter has autoincrementing ChapterId, foreign key to BookId and ChapterNo. And every time I add chapter to the book, I want ChapterNo to increment by one for the particular book this chapter belongs to.

It can be done by simple SQL statement: insert into chapter (BookId, ChapterNo) values (XXX, select max(ChapterNo) + 1 from chapter where BookId = XXX). But is there a way to do it in JPA and avoid race condition (which will happen if I read max ChapterNo first and then do the insert)

UPDATE: The only reasonable solution I came up with so far: implement DB trigger that takes care of incrementing ChapterNo. Then at least I don't need any native queries on JPA side

Comment: I think you should be able to do it by using a transaction and pessimistic locking to prevent anyone else from inserting a chapter at the same time. I know JPA has support for pessimistic locking but I do not know the details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not full solution, but there is a JPA feature with the [@OrderColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation.

Essentially you implement your @OneToMany relationship with a List, and JPA will persist the order of the elements in the list in a column in the database. Applied to the Book and Chapters it would be something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="book")
    @OrderColumn(name="chapterNo")
    private List<Chapter> chapters;
    ...
}
```

Note though, that this can result in many updates to the order column in case some element of the list changes. For instance, if you remove the first chapter and then persist the book, all the other chapters will be updated to reflect their new position in the list. Also you have no direct access to the chapterNo column to use in queries, just an implicit access through the index of the list.

Comment: this is interesting, thank you! with this approach, is it possible to reorder the list? i.e. if I want chapter 1 become 2 and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, if you reorder the list in memory, at the moment the transaction commits it will take care of updating the order column with the new values